# App Store developer renaming

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, publishing

I have a developer account for person, not a company. And I have my name written near every app that I published. Now I want to changed it to fancy name without changing my developer account and without registration of company.
Any help will be appreciated.

**I've changed approved answer because we are forced to start all law procedures to get legit papers for our company name and show it to Apple. Seems to be that this is the only way. :(**

Comment: For more detail u can mail them at this link asia.dev@asia.apple.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you, but as far as I know, the only way to have your real name changed into a "fancy" name is that you have a company with that name, which means that you've to go trough a hell of a mail exchange between you and apple, and you'll also have to provide some documentation that proves your company as existing.

Comment: My next step is to write a letter to Apple and then I'll post here what they say. I've read about documentation needed for companies, but also I sow some accounts with something like:

_Developer: John Johnson
<AppName> by MyCrazyGamesFactory_

Answer (score 0):

Answer founded in the [iOS Developer Support Center FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/):

You have to send an email.

> **How can I update or change my iOS Developer Program account information?**
>
> Please [contact us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) for assistance with:
>
> - Address changes
> - Contact information updates
> - Company/Organization name updates or changes

Look for more info here: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html

Answer (score 0):

You may need to either incorporate, or legally change your name, as Apple will likely ask to see the legal paperwork that your new fancy name is the legally recognized one for you or your corporation.