# Changing Developer Name in App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Let's assume that somehow my company manages to get the Developer name changed in the Developer Account at the App Store. In this case, what would happen to the existing apps:

1. Will the existing apps remain happily at the App Store without any effect?
2. Will I need to get new certificates from the Developer portal?
3. If yes, will I need to submit a new build of my Apps to the App Store?
4. If yes, will the bundle identifier of my subsequent releases would be different?
5. If yes, then how would the users be able to get updates to the apps?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Abizern - Where can I ask then?

Comment: The answer is that changing the name just affects the account. Changing the certificate (for normal app store distribution) does not affect apps currently in the store. It's covered in [Technical Note 2250](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html)

Comment: The reason I say that it is the wrong place is that isn't directly a programming question.

Comment: Thanks @Abizern I understand that it doesn't affect the app currently in store but what about the updates? Will the users still get updates to my app?

Answer (score 1):

I asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050136/app-store-developer-renaming), and we made renaming.
Non of our apps were forced to be resubmitted. We used all certificates with old names and it worked fine. I can't provide info about legal information that we send to Apple (not a coders did that), but one day we just saw another company name in the App Store and we did nothing to our apps.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It was really helpful.